# zbarSDK reader doesn't scan QR on fast devices (XCODE)

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, qr-code, zbar-sdk, zbar

I am using the zbarSDK on my IOS app. It works like a charm and it was perfect.
The problem is when I press on the Scan Button in front of a QR code (on fast device like 4s or iPhone 5), I only get the green rect and nothing happen, and I need to move the device for a second from the code and scan again and then it works.

If I click the Scan Button and then bring it to the QR code it works.

I was thinking on the following solutions but I don't know what best:

- How can I delay the reader from reading till the PresentModalView animation is finish.
- use something else instead of PresentModalView animated:YES.

Please advise

Comment: I would contact the makers of zbarSDK before you ask an question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did. I thought maybe someone run in to it and as an answer

Comment: I found out that it works when I use PresentModalView animated:NO